# libdbus reading array type result

Tags: c, dbus

I have to read org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.GetDevices

My program calls the method and receives result correctly.

The problem is how to support array of string/paths type?
How get length of the array and how to obtain single element,
Thanks.

Comment: What you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an array of not fixed-size elements (such as strings), we must call `dbus_message_iter_recurse(&args, &string);`, giving a pointer to the main iterator as args and pointer for new iterator as the second argument.

To obtain element, we call `dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&string, &paths);`, where `paths` is a pointer to a character array.

The whole code looks like below:

```html
if (!dbus_message_iter_init(msg, &args))
  fprintf(stderr, "Message has no arguments!\n");

  do {
    dbus_message_iter_recurse(&args, &string);
    do {

      dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&string, &paths);
      puts(paths);
    }
    while (dbus_message_iter_next(&string));
  } while (dbus_message_iter_next(&args));
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m glad you managed to fix your code, but please note that it’s recommended that you **don’t use libdbus-1** for connecting to D-Bus: its design is outdated, and is a pain to use correctly. It is, however, still maintained, unlike libdbus-glib.

It’s easier to use a more modern high-level API, such as [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html).

(libdbus-glib and libdbus-1 deliberately not linked to avoid giving them google juice.)